# How to Save a file with multiple delimiter in spark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to save a file delimited by `"|~"` characters but I get an error when I execute the command below. Can I save a file using multiple delimiters in Spark?

```
mydf1.coalesce(1).write.option("compression","none").format("csv").mode("Overwrite").option("delimiter","|~").save("my_hdfs_path")

// Error : pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u'Delimiter cannot be more than one character: |~'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, we are still waiting for an "official" solution, because the issue ["support for multiple delimiter in Spark CSV read"](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24540) is still open, and [SparkSQL](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/52671d631d2a64ed1cfa0c6e01168908faf92df8/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/csv/CsvOutputWriter.scala) still rely on [univocity-parsers](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers). In univocity CSV settings, the CSV delimiter can only be a single character, which constrains both the parser (reader) and generator (writer).

---

**Workarounds**

Finding a universally fast and safe way to write as CSV is hard. But depends on your data size and the complexity of CSV contents (date format? currency? quoting?), we may find a shortcut. Following are just some, hopefully inspiring, thoughts...

1. write to CSV with special character (say `⊢`) then substitute to `|~`.

   (haven't been benchmarked, but IMO it's very hopeful to be the fastest)

   ```
   df.coalesce(1).write.option("compression","none").option("delimiter", "⊢").mode("overwrite").csv("raw-output")
   ```

   then post-process with (ideally locally) with, say `sed`

   ```
   sed -i '.bak' 's/⊢/\|~/g' raw-output/*.csv
   ```
2. within PySpark, concatenate each row to a string, then write as a text file

   (can be flexible to deal with locality and special needs -- with a bit more work)

   ```py
   d = [{'name': 'Alice', 'age': 1},{'name':'Bob', 'age':3}]
   df = spark.createDataFrame(d, "name:string, age:int")

   df.show()

   #+-----+---+
   #| name|age|
   #+-----+---+
   #|Alice|  1|
   #|  Bob|  3|
   #+-----+---+


   @udf
   def mkstr(name, age):
       """
       for example, the string field {name} should be quoted with `"`
       """
       return '"{name}"|~{age}'.format(name=name, age=age)

   # unparse a CSV row back to a string
   df_unparsed = df.select(mkstr("name", "age").alias("csv_row"))
   df_unparsed.show()

   #+----------+
   #|   csv_row|
   #+----------+
   #|"Alice"|~1|
   #|  "Bob"|~3|
   #+----------+

   df_unparsed.coalesce(1).write.option("compression", "none").mode("overwrite").text("output")
   ```
3. `numpy.savetxt` allows multiple character as delimiter, so ...

   (numpy has lots of builtins if you cares about precisions of floating numbers)

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np

   # convert `Spark.DataFrame` to `Pandas.DataFrame`
   df_pd = df.toPandas()

   # use `numpy.savetxt` to save `Pandas.DataFrame`
   np.savetxt("a-long-day.csv", df_pd, delimiter="|~", fmt="%s")
   ```

Answer (score 0):

From Spark 3.0 We dont have this issue But if using prior version > Spark 2.3 This can be also used as solution. basically concatenating all column and fill null with  blank and write the data with the desired delimiter along with the header . This will more generic solution than hardcoding.This allows to have the header also retained.

```
    from pyspark.sql.functions import *
    from pyspark.sql import functions as F
    target_row_delimited = "|,"
    df=df.select([col(c).cast("string") for c in df.columns])
    df=df.na.fill("")
    headername=target_row_delimited.join(df.columns)
    df=df.withColumn(headername, concat_ws(target_row_delimited, *df.columns))
    df.select(df[headername].write.format("csv").mode(modeval).option("quoteAll", "false").option("quote","\u0000").option("header", "true").save(tgt_path + "/")
```

In case we need to read with multiple delimiters , the following solution can be avialed

```
source_delimiter = "|_|"
headcal = spark.read.text(source_filename)
headers = headcal.take(1)[0]['value']
header_column = headers.split(source_delimiter)
df = sc.textFile(source_filename).map(lambda x: x.split(source_delimiter)).toDF(header_column)
```